# jQuery data selector not matching .data

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute, jquery-data

I have a selector: `$('div.data[data="true"]').not('div.data[data-loading="true"]')`.

I am using `.data("data-loading","true")` on the element.

---

**Problem:**

Because `.data` doesn't truly set an attribute like `.prop` would, the above `.not` selector does not match elements which I have set the above `.data` to. Is there a selector I can use the match data set by `.data`, or must I use `.prop` in addition to/instead of `.data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no selectors that match data you put on your element via the `.data` function. In your case, you can readily make that an attribute, though. Your selector is already looking for an attribute, so just change

```
.data("data-loading","true")
```

to

```
.attr("data-loading","true")
```

The `div.data[data="true"]` selector won't work unless there's an attribute on the `div` with the name `data`, which as you've observed, there isn't (and shouldn't be, it would be an invalid attribute).

If you need to mark the divs that have data stored on them, I would use a class for that. I'd probably also use a class for the `data-loading` flag.